# apache local network

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, connection, local

I am trying to reach my local Apache from another source in the local network. The IP of the machine running Apache is 192.168.2.36, the os is xubuntu 12.04. Via this machine I can reach the Apache instance but it is not possible from any other pc or mobile device. The router's firewall is shut down.

```
sudo netstat -tulpen | grep apache
```

gives me either:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.36:80         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          1115713     4606/apache2
```

or (depending on configuration in ports.conf):

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          1115713     4606/apache2
```

Both do not work. 
The host machine in pingable by the other machines in the network.

I simply can not imagine why this turns out to be so difficult...

Comment: Local firewall on the server? what do you get with "sudo iptables -vL"?

Comment: No firewall on the server, please see the output of iptables -vL under http://pastebin.com/y3Z7qnVY

Comment: Try running nmap from one of the other machines and see if port 80 is in fact open on this server.

Comment: Yeah, tcpdumps, telnets and so on. No firewall? That pastebin looks like a gigantic, complicated firewall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you make a distinction between the other computers in the local network that can ping the Apache server and the remote PC/mobile devices that try to access the Apache server (and fail at it)? I mean, are they in the same network?

Just to make sure, and sorry for mentioning this if it's obvious to you: `192.168.2.36` is a private IP address which won't be routed and thus is not accessible from the Internet. The remote PC and mobile devices you mention **must** be located in the same local network in which the Apache server resides, or reachable through a **router of yours** (not your ISP's, unless you've configured it to forward some outside port to port 80 of your Apache server, of course -- I guess that's not the case).

I'll assume now that a remote PC is located in the same local network (let's say with IP address `192.168.2.100`).

1) First check that Apache can be accessed locally on `192.168.2.36` (you wrote that access from the server itself works - I list it here for the sake of completeness):

```
telnet 192.168.2.36 80
```

If you don't get something similar to this:

```
$ telnet 192.168.2.36 80
Trying 192.168.2.36...
Connected to 192.168.2.36.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

don't look further and check your Apache configuration/installation, for something doesn't work as it should.

If you see the output above Apache is running. Close the telnet session with Ctrl-] and proceed to 2).

2) Now let's see if any network traffic reaches 192.168.2.36 from the remote PC (192.168.2.100). On 192.168.2.36 type:

```
sudo tcpdump dst 192.168.2.36 and dst port 80
```

to dump any network packets with destination 192.168.2.36:80.

Now log into 192.168.2.100, type:

```
telnet 192.168.2.36 80
```

and then "GET /". That's an HTTP request, let's see if the server got it.

Go back to the tcpdump command and check its output. If it looks similar to this:

```
22:12:13.748106 IP 192.168.2.100.50272 > 192.168.2.36.http: Flags [S], seq 3557385561, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 239423238 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
22:12:13.748190 IP 192.168.2.100.50272 > 192.168.2.36.http: Flags [.], ack 1456211961, win 9186, options [nop,nop,TS val 239423238 ecr 239423238], length 0
```

packets are coming through, so proceed to 3).

If you don't see any packets from `192.168.2.100` test the steps above on a couple of other PCs in the local network. If you see the same behavior flush the firewall rules on `192.168.2.36`:

```
sudo iptables-save > /tmp/save
sudo iptables -F
```

and try again. If no packets reach `192.168.2.36` it's pretty difficult to say what's going wrong... some wild guesses are... but first restore the iptables configuration:

```
sudo iptables-restore < /tmp/save
```

I was saying, some wild guesses are: `192.168.2.36` or `192.168.2.100` has a corrupted ARP cache (list the ARP cache with arp -n and then delete the entries with arp -d *ip_address*), `192.168.2.36` has a defective ethernet card or cable, IP address `192.168.2.36` is used by another PC on the network, the remote PCs are configured to use IPv6...

3) Let's check whether IP packets are going back to `192.168.2.100`. Stop tcpdump with Ctrl-C and type:

```
sudo tcpdump dst 192.168.2.100 src port 80
```

to see any packets going back to `192.168.2.100` from source port 80 (that is, the Apache server). If you see an output similar to this:

```
23:03:33.054023 IP 192.168.2.36.http > 192.168.2.100.50471: Flags [S.], seq 1739061544, ack 502726814, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 242492771 ecr 242492771,sackOK,eol], length 0
23:03:33.054062 IP 192.168.2.36.http > 192.168.2.100.50471: Flags [.], ack 1, win 9186, options [nop,nop,TS val 242492771 ecr 242492771], length 0
23:03:34.344572 IP 192.168.2.36.http > 192.168.2.100.50471: Flags [.], ack 8, win 9186, options [nop,nop,TS val 242494052 ecr 242494052], length 0
```

packets are going back. Proceed to 4).

No tcpdump output means that `192.168.2.100` is not getting any packets back... maybe a firewall? And from another remote PC, same behavior? ARP problem (list the ARP cache with arp -n and then delete the entries with arp -d *ip_address*)?

4) Check the output of the telnet command above. If it looks similar to this:

```
Trying 192.168.2.36.... 
Connected to 192.168.2.36. 
Escape character is '^]'. 
GET / 
Location: http://192.168.2.36 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

there may be a problem with your web browser. Maybe the HTTP proxy doesn't exclude computers in the local network?

Comment: What a fantastically detailed and helpful response. Welcome to SO and Server Fault.